# ORM additional computed column in some scenarios?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

I am using the latest version of NHibernate, and I recently stumbled upon an interesting problem.

Let's say I have a table called Profile, and I want to receive a list of all my profiles. However, with it, I have a computed column called `CanDelete` which prohibits the profile from being deleted if (for instance) it is in use.

However, this `CanDelete` computed column is not part of my entity and I don't want to pollute the entity when I only need the `CanDelete` value in this scenario - and computing it individually for every profile is too slow.

Is there a way in NHibernate to execute some query and fetch the rows of that query as objects, but then somehow fetch an additional computed column as well?

Let's say I am using an N-tier architecture. All the way in the presentation layer I need a list of all profiles (and for each profile, whether or not I can delete it). How would my Business Logic Layer and Data Access Layer look like?

Right now in my repository I have a `GetProfiles` method and then a `CanDeleteProfile` method that I run for every profile fetched. But like I mentioned above, it is simply too slow. I could make a `GetProfilesWithCanDeleteStatus` method, but that would require me to create a specialized entity with that computed column on it as well.

What are your suggestions on how to architect this in a proper way when I don't want to hit `O(n^2)` performance in my profiles list? I would like to avoid the n+1 problem.

*I am not necessarily looking for an NHibernate solution (I tagged NHibernate because it might have some specific tools for this kind of thing), and general solutions for other ORMs are welcome.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea that might be good for you, but it won't be a perfect one since each way you design your program has it's downsides.

I suggest you change the definition of that column `CanDelete` so it would be just like any other column in that entity (not computed at run time) and of type Boolean, but without damaging the requirements.

By doing so it would be like any other simple `Select` from  the db - which is very quick.

Now, the tricky part is to insure that the column would indicate (at any time needed ) if it is been used or not (and if it can be deleted).

because I don't know the way you compute if Profile entity is been used (and can be deleted) it's difficult to tell how to design the DAL and BL exactly, but the guideline is :
in every other place you change a state in DB (of that entity or other) that might change the column `CanDelete` you encapsulate with a function to compute that value again to validate it's state and change it if needed.

If you insure that every time you change in BL one of the columns which `CanDelete` is computed from than you insure that the column `CanDelete` is always true indication.

The downside for this approach is : 
1. It opens a place for mistake of a programmer not using the encapsulated function when needed.
2. It takes an assumption the this app is the only one changing this db.
3. You have to be careful from inserting raw data from an Management studio or script.

I Hope it's good for your BL.